# Move items from one row to another when screen size changes Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On my page I have a calendar, I want it to be responsive, so that On Large screens it will look like this:

```
[Jan]  [Feb] [Mar] 
[Apr]  [May] [June]
[July] [Aug] [Sept]
[Oct]  [Nov] [Dec]
```

When resizing to middle this:

```
[Jan]  [Feb]
[Mar]  [Apr]
[May]  [June]
[July] [Aug] 
[Sept] [Oct]
[Nov]  [Dec]
```

The problem is that I group them by 3 elements to one row (large screens view).
(I assigned these classes to my "months": `class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"`)
So when I change screen size to middle it is still grouped in rows and looks so:

```
[Jan]  [Feb]
[Mar]
[Apr]  [May]
[June]
[July] [Aug]
[Sept]
[Oct]  [Nov]
[Dec]
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Please post the code you have written for this so we can actually help you.

Comment: You could just float all of the months and not place them in their own columns and rows, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/9a7g6k3f/), and constrain the container size.

Comment: You could do the same thing and keep the Bootstrap stuff but don't put each set of months in their own row. Add all months to a single row, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/9a7g6k3f/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use one `.row` and use `.clearfix visible-lg-block` for large screens at each 3nth item. See Bootstrap Docs about [Responsive Columns Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

```css
[class^="col-"] {
  border: solid red;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Jan</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Feb</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Mar</div>
     <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Apr</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">May</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Jun</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Jul</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Aug</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Sep</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Oct</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Nov</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">Dez</div>
  </div>
</div>
```